# How can I tell cabal to specify a dependency for one of my program's dependencies?

Tags: haskell, constraints, cabal

This is actually a follow-on question to [How can I tell Cabal which dependency to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657334/how-can-i-tell-cabal-which-dependency-to-use).

The package `haskell-src-meta` has two dependencies:

```
template-haskell >=2.7 && <2.9,
template-haskell >=2.4 && <2.7
```

and `template-haskell 2.7` won't build on my system. I know the solution to this is:

```
cabal install --constraint="template-haskell == 2.5.0.0" haskell-src-meta
```

However, I now want to write my own cabal file for the software I've written that has these dependencies. It doesn't seem to be enough to have:

```
Build-depends: template-haskell-2.5.0.0
```

Instead, I actually want to say that `haskell-src-meta` is a build dependency, but further tell cabal that it should install that dependency with the same `constraint` specified above. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the "installed" constraint is what you want.

```
cabal install --constraint "template-haskell installed" my-custom-package
```

Comment: Perhaps, though it seems a shame to have to leak that to all the (imagined) users who install my software. I'd rather they only had to type `cabal install my-app` and be able to bake that `template-haskell` dependency into my cabal file.

Comment: @NoahDaniels Hm. You want to require other people to use `template-haskell-2.5.0.0` because the other versions of `template-haskell` won't build on your computer? That seems like a bad idea, since people should be using the version of `template-haskell` that comes with their compiler, and not attempting to build a different version.

Comment: It appears that `template-haskell` versions are `ghc` version-dependent. What I'd ideally like to do is map `ghc` version to appropriate `template-haskell` version, and solve the problem that way.

Comment: @NoahDaniels It's not yet clear in my head what the problem that you're trying to solve *is*.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with Hackage. GHC 7.0 comes with `template-haskell-2.5.0.0`, but cabal sees that `template-haskell-2.7.0.0` is on Hackage. So `cabal-install` decides to install `template-haskell-2.7.0.0` when installing `haskell-src-meta`, but this obviously doesn't work, since ghc needs its own version of `template-haskell`. It seems the correct solution would be to remove `template-haskell` from Hackage.

Comment: @reinerp New versions of cabal-install will attempt not to reinstall things (vis-a-vis the "modular" constraint solver). So in the future, such drastic measures may not be necessary. =)